# How to separate a number according to the Indian numbering system in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit, number-with-delimiter

I have used `number_with_delimiter` method for adding commas for numbers in an invoice in Ruby on Rails. But the number format resulted in `23,324,455` and not as `2,33,24,455` that is, [Indian Rupees format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).

```
<%= number_with_precision(@number, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',') %>
```

I have to generate Invoice with amount in Rupees so the format should be `xx,xx,xxx.00`. Is it possible in Rails? How to accomplish it?

This can be done with JavaScript but the problem is, I have generated the invoice in PDF format using PDFKit gem which does not respond with JavaScript. I have used the required js code on loading the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.totalvalue').each(function(){
    value = $('.totalvalue').text();
    $('.totalvalue').html(
      (value+"").split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g,        '$1,').split("").reverse().join("")
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you @stefan for editing the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`money`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem, and specifically explore its [formatting options](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/money/Money/Formatting).

```
Money.new(10000000, "INR").format(:symbol => false, 
                                  :south_asian_number_formatting => true)    
#=> "1,00,000.00"
```

Comment: this works fine but as you have mentioned, when the amount is 10000000, it gives 1,00,000.00 but what I expect is 1,00,00,000.00 and also when it has decimal point like 123456.5 it gives 1,234.56 instead of 1,23,456.50

Comment: @Nandy  That gem works with paise - so the value should be specified in paise, not in rupees.  As per documentation, `Represents monetary values as integers, in cents. This avoids floating point rounding errors.`

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but works:

```
("%.2f" % 23324455).reverse.gsub(/(?<=.{6})(\d\d?)/, ',\1').reverse
# => "2,33,24,455.00"
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation? It's not obvious how this is working.